# how to return to main menu after completing processes

Tags: python

```
import random
import math

main_menu = ["1 - Display Balance","2 - Withdraw Funds","3 - Deposit Funds","9 - Return Card"]
print("Welcome to Northern Frock")
print(main_menu[0])
print(main_menu[1])
print(main_menu[2])
print(main_menu[3])

atm_input_1 = int(input("Select 1 to display the current balance and the maximum amount available for withdrawal (In £10 increments) \n select 2 to view avalaible withdrawal amounts \n Select 3 to deposit funds \n select 9 to return card!"))
current_balance = random.randint(10,1000)
withdrawal_balance = math.floor(current_balance/10)*10

if atm_input_1 == 1:
    
    print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
    
    print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

elif atm_input_1 == 2:
    sub_menu = ["1 - £10","2 - £20","3 - £40","4 - £60","5 - £80","6 - £100","7 - Other amount","8 - Return to main menu"]
    print("Please select withdrawal amount")
    print(sub_menu[0])
    print(sub_menu[1])
    print(sub_menu[2])
    print(sub_menu[3])
    print(sub_menu[4])
    print(sub_menu[5])
    print(sub_menu[6])
    print(sub_menu[7])

    sub_menu_input = int(input("Please select a number from the options below"))
    if (sub_menu_input == 1 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£10 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 10
            withdrawal_balance - 10
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")
    elif (sub_menu_input == 2 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£20 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 20
            withdrawal_balance - 20
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    

    elif (sub_menu_input == 3 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£40 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 40
            withdrawal_balance - 40
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    
    
    elif (sub_menu_input == 4 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£60 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 60
            withdrawal_balance - 60
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    

    elif (sub_menu_input == 5 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£80 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 80
            withdrawal_balance - 80
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    

    elif (sub_menu_input == 6 ):
        if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
            print("£100 successfully withdrawed from account")
            current_balance - 100
            withdrawal_balance - 100
            print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
            print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

        else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")

    elif(sub_menu_input == 7):
         withdrawal_request = int(input("Please enter amount you wish to withdraw (In a £10 sequence"))
         if withdrawal_request % 10 == 0:
                if withdrawal_balance >= withdrawal_request:
                    print("£",withdrawal_balance,"successfully withdrawed from account")
                    current_balance - withdrawal_request
                    withdrawal_balance - withdrawal_request
                    print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                    print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

         else:print("ERROR Invalid withdrawal request")

elif atm_input_1 == 3:
    deposit_request = int(input("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit into your account"))
    current_balance = current_balance + deposit_request
    withdrawal_balance = math.floor((withdrawal_balance + deposit_request)/10)*10
    print("you have successfully deposited £",deposit_request,"into your account")
    print("updated balances:")
    print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
    print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)

elif atm_input_1 == 9:
    print("Card returned , thank you for banking with Northern Frock good day")
    quit()

else: print("Error invalid selection try again")
```

> QUESTION(I can do all the requirements however i am struggling to have my code return to the main >menu after completing the withdraws/depoists/balance checks ?)

> Write a program that simulates the behaviour of a basic ATM.
>
> Follow the instructions below:
>
> 1. Print a main menu:
>
> Welcome to Northern Frock
>
> 2. 1 - Display balance
> 3. 2 - Withdraw funds
> 4. 3 - Deposit funds
> 5. 9 - Return card Enter an option: 6. If ‘1’ is entered, display the current balance and the maximum amount available for withdrawal (must
>    be a multiple of £10), and return to main menu. 7. If ‘2’ is entered,
>    print a sub-menu with withdrawal amounts of: Please select withdrawal
>    amount 8. 1 - £10 9. 2 - £20 10. 3 - £40 11. 4 - £60 12. 5 - £80 13. 6
>
> - £100 14. 7 - Other amount 15. 8 - Return to main menu Enter an option: a. If ‘1 to 6’’ is selected check that the requested
>   withdrawal is allowed, print a message to show that the money has been
>   withdrawn, calculate the new balance and return to main menu. b. If
>   ‘7’ is selected, then prompt the user for an integer value. Check this
>   number is a multiple of 10 and that the withdrawal is permitted, print
>   a message to show that the money has been withdrawn, calculate the new
>   balance and return to main menu. c. If ‘8’ is selected return to main
>   menu. 16. If ‘3’ is entered, provide another menu that will allow the
>   user to enter an amount to deposit (does not need to be a multiple of
>   £10), return to main menu or return card. If funds are deposited,
>   provide appropriate feedback and update the balance and return to main
>   menu. 17. If ‘9’ is entered, print a goodbye message and exit (break).
>
> 18. If another value is entered, print an error message and print the menu again.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use loops?  Your total lines of code could be reduced by about 2/3rds if you are.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to put the entire program in an endless loop like so:

```
import random
import math

while True:
    main_menu = ["1 - Display Balance","2 - Withdraw Funds","3 - Deposit Funds","9 - Return Card"]
    print("Welcome to Northern Frock")
    print(main_menu[0])
    print(main_menu[1])
    print(main_menu[2])
    print(main_menu[3])
    
    atm_input_1 = int(input("Select 1 to display the current balance and the maximum amount available for withdrawal (In £10 increments) \n select 2 to view avalaible withdrawal amounts \n Select 3 to deposit funds \n select 9 to return card!"))
    current_balance = random.randint(10,1000)
    withdrawal_balance = math.floor(current_balance/10)*10
    
    if atm_input_1 == 1:
        
        print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
        
        print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
    elif atm_input_1 == 2:
        sub_menu = ["1 - £10","2 - £20","3 - £40","4 - £60","5 - £80","6 - £100","7 - Other amount","8 - Return to main menu"]
        print("Please select withdrawal amount")
        print(sub_menu[0])
        print(sub_menu[1])
        print(sub_menu[2])
        print(sub_menu[3])
        print(sub_menu[4])
        print(sub_menu[5])
        print(sub_menu[6])
        print(sub_menu[7])
    
        sub_menu_input = int(input("Please select a number from the options below"))
        if (sub_menu_input == 1 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£10 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 10
                withdrawal_balance - 10
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")
        elif (sub_menu_input == 2 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£20 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 20
                withdrawal_balance - 20
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    
    
        elif (sub_menu_input == 3 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£40 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 40
                withdrawal_balance - 40
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    
        
        elif (sub_menu_input == 4 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£60 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 60
                withdrawal_balance - 60
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    
    
        elif (sub_menu_input == 5 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£80 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 80
                withdrawal_balance - 80
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")    
    
        elif (sub_menu_input == 6 ):
            if (withdrawal_balance >= 10):
                print("£100 successfully withdrawed from account")
                current_balance - 100
                withdrawal_balance - 100
                print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
            else: print("Sorry you currrently have insufficent funds for a withdrawal")
    
        elif(sub_menu_input == 7):
             withdrawal_request = int(input("Please enter amount you wish to withdraw (In a £10 sequence"))
             if withdrawal_request % 10 == 0:
                    if withdrawal_balance >= withdrawal_request:
                        print("£",withdrawal_balance,"successfully withdrawed from account")
                        current_balance - withdrawal_request
                        withdrawal_balance - withdrawal_request
                        print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
                        print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
             else:print("ERROR Invalid withdrawal request")
    
    elif atm_input_1 == 3:
        deposit_request = int(input("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit into your account"))
        current_balance = current_balance + deposit_request
        withdrawal_balance = math.floor((withdrawal_balance + deposit_request)/10)*10
        print("you have successfully deposited £",deposit_request,"into your account")
        print("updated balances:")
        print("Current Balance:","£",current_balance)
        print("Withdrawal Balance:","£",withdrawal_balance)
    
    elif atm_input_1 == 9:
        print("Card returned , thank you for banking with Northern Frock good day")
        quit()
    
    else: print("Error invalid selection try again")
```

then whenever you want to stop the program just make a "break" statement in order to exit the loop.